# Ext Js : Hide all element or items inside container

Tags: extjs

I have multiple container with field. Basically when container is hidden all field's are  not visible. but I was checked "hidden" property or "isHidden()" method of field. I am getting as false.
I want make it as true when container is hidden and false when it is visible.
How to make field are hidden and show by using override

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very hard to read. (Poor English) But if I understand correctly you hide a container with fields. If you then check the `isHidden()` of one of the fields, it returns false. That is standard Ext behavior. The container is hidden not the fields. What you can do is query down and set the fields hidden.

E.g.

```
Ext.define('MyCustomContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    hide: function () {
        var me = this;
        Ext.each(me.query('field'), function (field) {
            field.hide();
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    },
    show: function () {
        var me = this;
        Ext.each(me.query('field'), function (field) {
            field.show();
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

You ask:
I don't want to create custom component. Can I do same thing by using override?

Yes you can!

I hope you don't have an `Ext.Container` as type it's kind of dirty overriding it for ALL containers, but it will work... => it would be better to replace `Ext.Container` with the specific type of your container...

```
Ext.define('YourApp.override.Container', {
    override: 'Ext.Container',
    hide: function () {
        var me = this;
        Ext.each(me.query('field'), function (field) {
            field.hide();
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    },
    show: function () {
        var me = this;
        Ext.each(me.query('field'), function (field) {
            field.show();
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: i don't want to create custom component. can i do same thing by using override?